# How to use HttpClient for OAuth2.0 requests västrafik api

Tags: c#, swift, dotnet-httpclient

How to use HttpClient in C#? . I have tried to implemented this but with no success. I am stuck and appreciate some help :)

Bellow is some swift code that is working and afterward c# code that display what I have tried to do. Thanks in advance.

Generate token:

```
 POST https://api.vasttrafik.se/token HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Basic UmJseEkyeTFsWVNFTTZ0Z2J6anBTa2E0R1o6Wk1nSkR0Y0paRGV4OTJldUxpQUdYOFExUnU=
    grant_type=client_credentials&scope=<device_id>
```

swift code:

```
let data = ("\(Constants.key):\(Constants.secret)").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64 = data!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let parameters = [
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": "\(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)"
    ]

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic \(base64)",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    if let expires = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "expires") as? Date, let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "token") as? String {
        if expires > Date() {
            completionHandler(token)
            return
        }
    }

    Alamofire.request(Constants.tokenURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                if let token = json["access_token"] as? String, let expires = json["expires_in"] as? Int {
                    let date = Date()
                    let expiresTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: expires, to: date)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(expiresTime, forKey: "expires")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
                    completionHandler(token)
                }
            }
    }
```

I have tried to do so but with no success. c# code:

```
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_nyckel + ":" + _hemlighet);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));


            /*
             *  Connect to the server 
             */


            var strin = Injected.Instance.Platform.GetId();
            var base54 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

            var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials&scope=" + Injected.Instance.Platform.GetId())
            });

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(page, stringContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Comment: If you're trying to follow `Oauth2` standard then your `Authorization` header value has to start with "Bearer" e.g. `"Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"`. Also your `base64` value looks like the data you want to send and not your access token, so definitely not something you put in your header.

Comment: @Mikael `NativeMessageHandler` ? What's that, except an abandoned project called `ModernHttpClient`? HttpClient in the Full framework *does* use the native WinHttp library. In .NET Core it uses a newer, faster managed one.

Comment: There are no OAuth-specific requirements for HttpClient. It simply makes HTTP calls using verbs, headers etc. It's a matter of setting the correct headers and creating appropriate requests. If you have problems (what exactly?) it could be due to that third-party handler

Comment: Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to inspect what's actually being sent from your program and what is returned by the server. Does it look the same? You don't have to set the `Content-Type` header explicitly, the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class will do that.

Comment: Finally a 10 second timeout is *too little*. DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds if not more. You can avoid that if you reuse the same `httpClient` instance. HttpClient is thread-safe and meant to be reused to avoid such delays as DNS resolution or TLS negotiation

Comment: I using Xamarin and this code runnings in a core PCL projekt so I have not access to all libs. :( Thanks for all help so far

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following code.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.vasttrafik.se");
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", Injected.Instance.Platform.GetId())
                });

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes));

                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                var result = await client.PostAsync("token",content);
                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
```